# Convert SVG animation to image sequence

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-animate

I am trying to render images from SVG Animation.
Here is my code.
https://jsfiddle.net/d3bhfa1L/2/

It generating images sequence but not able to capture animation from SVG.

I actually want to convert SVG animation to mp4 format but not able to find any direct solution. So trying to convert SVG animation to an image sequence and then convert image sequence to mp4 video.

```
/* uniformly named URL object */
var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

/* our snapshotting class */
function svg_snapshot(svg_ref, fps, seconds) {

    /* DOM object element */
    this.svg_ref = svg_ref;

    /* svg xml root */
    // this.svg_root = svg_ref.contentDocument.documentElement;
    this.svg_root = svg_ref;

    /* frames per second */
    this.fps = fps;

    /* total animation duration in seconds */
    this.seconds = seconds;

    this.svg_root.pauseAnimations();

    this.make_step = function (step, time) {
        if (time > this.seconds * 1000) {
            // animation ended
            return false;
        }

        /* pause for snapshot */
        this.svg_root.pauseAnimations();

        /* save actual svg state as XML */
        var svg_xml = this.svg_root.outerHTML;

        /* disable animation elements with simple replacing */
        svg_xml = svg_xml.replace(new RegExp('<animate', 'g'), '<not_anim');

        /* save as blob */
        var svg_data = new Blob([svg_xml], {
            type: 'image/svg+xml'
        });

        /* create data url (creates browsers interal blob: data link) */
        var data_url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg_data);

        /* create bitmap */
        var img = new Image();

        /* save class reference */
        var self = this;

        /* mount load process */
        img.onload = function () {

            self.make_step_next(step, time, this);

        };

        /* set image url */
        img.src = data_url;

    };

    this.make_step_next = function (step, time, img) {

        /* create canvas */
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

        canvas.setAttribute("width", this.svg_ref.clientWidth);
        canvas.setAttribute("height", this.svg_ref.clientHeight);

        canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";

        /* get canvas 2d contextr */
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        /* drav loaded image onto it */
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        /* here we can get dataURL (base64 encoded url with image content) */
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        /*
            and here you can do whatever you want - send image
            by ajax (that base64 encoded url which you can decode
            on serverside) or draw somewhere on page
        */
        var finalImg = document.createElement("IMG");

        finalImg.src = dataURL;
        finalImg.style.border = "1px solid black";

        document.body.appendChild(finalImg);


        /*
            let animation continue - before image is loaded, the
            animation is paused - by this is achieved perfect
            timing in this serial process
        */
        this.svg_root.unpauseAnimations();

        var self = this;
        var interval = 1000 / this.fps; // one frame interval

        setTimeout(function () {
            self.make_step(step + 1, time + interval);
        }, interval);

    };

}

/* usage - parameters: SVG DOM ref, frames per second, duration in seconds */
var item_ref = new svg_snapshot(document.getElementById('Content-R'), 30, 1);

/* start snapshotting */
item_ref.make_step(0, 0);
```

Comment: If you want to convert SVG to mp4, can you not use something like [svg to mp4](https://sendeyo.com/onlineconverter/en/svg/mp4)?

Comment: @tmach I want to convert through coding.

Comment: svg_to_mp4 doesn't work, or at least doesn't seem to work with SVGs that include CSS animations. I just tried it on two of my own. These include CSS animation commands generated by my own animation engine. The site just produced static images. And yes, I did select "MP4", not "JPG"!

Answer (score 0):

All the css dont work for svg elements, They have specific attributes that works.
Try using **gsap** animation engine.

1. Try to work with SVG
2. Animate svg objects using gsap
3. On update event of gsap, export svg frames (You can use SVG.js library)
   You can use the following function to export:

   ```
    function saveSvg(svgData) {
        var svgBlob = new Blob([svgData], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        console.log(svgBlob);
        var svgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.href = svgUrl;
        downloadLink.download = "newesttree.svg";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    }

    // Call it like this(USING SVG.JS LIBRARY):
    let main_svg = SVG('#id_of_your_svg_root');
    saveSvg(main_svg.svg());
   ```
4. The above will download the svg files
5. Use an svg encoder such as **ffmpeg** to combine files to video

Answer (score -1):

i know this is one year old, but now i needed to solve this thing, because actual chrome stopped updating SVG element properties in dom during animations (path data etc.) so the code no loger works. (i am the author of the sample code btw)

There is probably no way now how to snap frames from SVG SMIL animation. But in SVG CSS animations is possible with window.getComputedStyle.

And i see your animation is done that way - so i used it to figure it out and here is updated working example (in Chrome):

```
    /* uniformly named URL object */
    var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

    /* our snapshotting class */
    function svg_snapshot(svg_ref, fps, seconds, correction) {

        var self = this;

        /* DOM object element */
        this.svg_ref = svg_ref;

        /* svg xml root */
        //this.svg_root = svg_ref.contentDocument.documentElement;
        this.svg_root = svg_ref;

        /* frames per second */
        this.fps = fps;

        /* total animation duration in seconds */
        this.seconds = seconds;

        /* frame msec correction (to fix getComputedStyle bug which shifts a little animation) */
        this.correction = correction;

        /* list of possible elements (it probably not complete) */
        this.elements = ['path', 'circle', 'g'];

        /* list of possible styles */
        this.styleKeys = ['d', 'fill', 'fill-opacity', 'stroke', 'stroke-dasharray', 'stroke-dashoffset', 'stroke-linecap', 'stroke-linejoin', 'stroke-misterlimit', 'stroke-opacity', 'stroke-width', 'opacity', 'transform'];

        this.svg_element_list = {};

        /* load specific element lists from svg */
        this.elements.forEach(function(elementName) {

            var sf, els = self.svg_root.getElementsByTagName(elementName);

            self.svg_element_list[elementName] = [];

            for (sf = 0; sf < els.length; sf++) {
                self.svg_element_list[elementName].push({
                    "ref": els.item(sf),
                    "style": null
                });
            }
        });

        this.toggle_pause = function(flag) {
            var self = this;

            /* pause and save computed style when paused */
            this.elements.forEach(function(elementName) {
                self.svg_element_list[elementName].forEach(function(c) {
                    c["ref"].style.animationPlayState = flag ? "paused" : "";
                    c["style"] = flag ? getComputedStyle(c["ref"]) : null;
                });
            });
        };

        this.toggle_pause(true);

        this.make_step = function(step) {

            /* pause for snapshot */
            this.toggle_pause(true);

            if (step > this.fps * this.seconds) {
                // animation ended
                return false;
            }

            /* save object reference */
            var self = this;

            /* capture snapped svg xml string */
            var xml_data = this.svg_root.outerHTML;

            /* parse snapped svg frame as object DOM structure */
            var svg_xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml_data, "text/xml");

            /* remove style elements (it may damage snapshotted svg and will be rewritten imidietly by inline styles) */
            var sf, styleEls = svg_xml.getElementsByTagName('style');

            for (sf = styleEls.length - 1; sf >= 0; sf--) {
                styleEls[sf].parentNode.removeChild(styleEls[sf]);
            }

            /* loop trough possible elements and copy */
            this.elements.forEach(function(elementName) {

                /* capture the processed style */
                /* paths in snapped svg */
                var elsSnap = svg_xml.getElementsByTagName(elementName);

                for (var sf = 0; sf < self.svg_element_list[elementName].length; sf++) {
                    var cStyle = self.svg_element_list[elementName][sf]["style"];

                    /* enforce computed styles state */
                    self.styleKeys.forEach(function(stKey) {
                        elsSnap[sf].style[stKey] = cStyle.getPropertyValue(stKey);
                    });
                }
            });

            /* save as blob with a help of XMLserializer (using object DOM structure) */
            var svg_data = new Blob([(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg_xml)], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});

            /* create data url (creates browsers interal blob: data link) */
            var data_url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg_data);

            /* create bitmap */
            var img = new Image();

            /* mount load process */
            img.onload = function() {

                self.make_step_next(step, this);

            };

            /* set image url */
            img.src = data_url;

        };

        this.make_step_next = function(step, img) {
            var self = this;

            /* create canvas */
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

            canvas.setAttribute("width", this.svg_ref.clientWidth);
            canvas.setAttribute("height", this.svg_ref.clientHeight);

            canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";

            /* get canvas 2d contextr */
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            /* drav loaded image onto it */
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            /* here we can get dataURL (base64 encoded url with image content) */
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

            /* and here you can do whatever you want - send image by ajax (that base64 encoded url which you can decode on serverside) or draw somewhere on page */
            var finalImg = document.createElement("IMG");

            finalImg.style.border = "1px solid black";

            /* add frame number to image alt */
            /* it might represent file name etc. */
            var frameId = "000" + step;
            finalImg.alt = "frame" + frameId.substr(frameId.length - 3);

            finalImg.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById("image_stack").appendChild(finalImg);

                self.make_step_go(step + 1);
            };

            finalImg.src = dataURL;
        };

        this.make_step_go = function(step) {
            var self = this;
            var interval = 1000 / this.fps - this.correction; // one frame interval

            setTimeout(function() {
                self.make_step(step);
            }, interval);

            /* let animation continue - before image is loaded, the animation is paused - by this is achieved perfect timing in this serial process */
            this.toggle_pause(false);
        };
    }
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p275rmah/

Note: the window.getComputedStyle method has a bug or unexpected behavior which somehow moves animation forward with each read of property value. I did not find any other way how to prevent this other than put some correction to the time interval - which will be specific for each different SVG.

The code might not work for all SVG animations - but some cases may be solved easily by updating this.styleKeys and this.elements properties.